# Truffle beta Contract.at is supposed to be a promise

Tags: web3js, truffle, testing

I'm trying to test a contract with Truffle beta (because of the new web3 1.0.0 support).

When i try to create the contract object by using `Contract = artifacts.require("Contract"); contract = Contract.at(Contract.address);` and subsequently logging `console.log(contract)` it returns a pending promise.

I read the [release notes](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta.0) and under 'breaking changes' it says that the `.at` function is now async. But when I try to prefix `await` to `contract = await Contract.at(Contract.address);` I get an error saying that the `at` function is in fact **not** async.

I noticed this error when I tried to call a function with `contract.methods.myFunction(argument).call()` and there was an error saying there is no 'methods' for undefined.

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing the `contract = await Contract.at(Contract.address)` with the `Contract.deployed()` function.

But I had to put the `contract` declaration inside each `it` block. With the older truffle version it used to work if it's declared once inside the `contract` block.

Many thanks to the people in the Gitter channel who helped me solve this problem!

Comment: 1. "But I had to put the contract declaration inside each `it`" - you can declare `var contract` at a global scope, and then put the initialization of it (once) in a `before` clause.

Comment: 2. "But when I try to prefix `await`... I get an error saying that the `at` function is in fact not `async` - it is in fact the scope in which you were using this `await`, which gave you the error. You can use `await` on both `async` and non-`async` function calls, but you can use it only inside `async` functions, which apparently you didn't (until you put it inside the `it`).

Comment: 3. I recommend replacing `contract` with a different variable name, because this symbol already exists in Truffle scope.